# Question about restricted/unrestricted formulas in Henkin, Monk, and Tarski's "Cylindric Algebras, Part II"

Tags: logic, notation

In the discussion of connections between logic and cylindric algebras (section 4.3) in Henkin, Monk, and Tarski's *Cylindric Algebras, Part II*, they introduce the notion of a "restricted" formula (p. 152), shown in the included picture.

[image: Definition of Restricted Formula]

Here, the symbol $\rho$ denotes their rank function, which assigns an ordinal $\leq \alpha$ to each relation symbol.

The crucial bit I'm not quite getting is what is going on with the displayed formula, where the variables are of the form, e.g., $v_{\kappa 0}$. Restricted formulas differ by dropping $\kappa$, but I'm not sure what $\kappa$ is doing in the first place. Is $\kappa \eta$ just supposed to be read as multiplication? Something else?

Comment: I believe that $^{\rho\xi}\alpha$ denotes the functions mapping $\alpha$ to $\rho\xi$.  If that's correct, $\kappa\eta$ is function application.  My belief is based on similar conventions being used by Don Monk in his *Mathematical Logic*.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi You are absolutely right, with the minor caveat that I think you have the mapping reversed here -- I believe they use it for the set of functions mapping $\rho\epsilon$ to $\alpha$. I don't know why I missed function application! Thanks! (If you want to convert your comment to an answer I'd be happy to accept it.)

Comment: Yes, I have switched domain and co-domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that $^{\rho\xi}\alpha$ denotes the functions mapping $\rho\xi$ to $\alpha$. If that's correct, $\kappa\eta$ is function application. My belief is based on similar conventions being used by Don Monk in his *Mathematical Logic* and *Introduction to Set Theory*.